# How to add interative value to each line of a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

```
Numlines=$(grep "" -c file.txt) # This works
for line in $( seq 1 $Numlines) # for each line 
do
sed "s/$/ Line${i}/" file.txt # not right
done
```

file.txt:

```
this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the third line
```

desired output

```
this is the first line  Line1
this is the second line  Line2
this is the third line  Line3
```

Instead I am getting:

```
this is the first line Line1
this is the second line Line1
this is the third line Line1
this is the first line Line2
this is the second line Line2
this is the third line Line2
this is the first line Line3
this is the second line Line3
this is the third line Line3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is going to process the whole file `Numlines` times, adding the suffix to every line regardless. Also your loop variable is `$line` whereas you use `$i` in the sed command, and your assignment of `Numlines` is syntactically incorrect in most shells.

You *could* do

```
Numlines=$(wc -l < file.txt)
for i in $(seq 1 "$Numlines"); do sed -n "${i}s/$/ Line${i}/p" file.txt; done
```

Note that assignments like `Numlines=$(wc -l < file.txt)` or your original

```
Numlines = $(grep "" -c file.txt) # This works
```

(it probably doesn't) must not have whitespace around the `=` in bash and similar shells.

However using a shell loop to process files in this way is inefficient - it would be better IMHO to use something like the following in awk:

```
awk '{$(NF+1) = "Line" FNR} 1' file.txt
```

or more-or-less equivalently in perl:

```
perl -lpe '$_ .= " Line $."' file.txt
```

---

If sed is the only tool available to you, then you could use it twice - once using the `=` command to number the lines, then a second time to format the result:

```
sed = file.txt | sed '$!N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 Line\1/'
```

Comment: Ha, yes you are correct, that line doesn't work. I added the spaces when posting to make it more readable to people without realizing it made it nonreadable to bash (have corrected the post).  I have never tried perl but your solution with awk works perfectly. Thanks, once again, steeldriver.  Also, can you tell me what is the second to last character doing (the 1)?

Comment: @Insideup awk programs consist of `pattern {action}` pairs; the `{action}` is executed if `pattern` evaluates TRUE. There is a default pattern `{print}` which gets executed if no explicit `{action}` is given. `1` is just the simplest pattern that evaluates TRUE to trigger this default action.